# how to make a java class to be an attribute of the other class

Tags: java, attributes

Java noob here.Could you please model a simple scenario where one java class would be an attribute of the other class? Lets say classes 'Owner' with no specified attributes yet and a class 'Car' with attributes: model,ccEngine, owner. 
So class Car has an attribute 'owner' of class Owner. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `class Owner { Car car; }`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car {

  Owner owner;
  String model;
  int ccEngine;

}

public class Owner{

  //Example attributes
  String name;
  int yearOfBirth;

}
```

This way you can set an instance of Owner to an instance of Car. (1 to 1 relation).

If the classes are in different packages, don't forget to import the package of class Owner in class Car.